# Android In-App Billing - user ID in signed JSON

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

When you verify signed JSON which comes when a user has completed transaction there is obvious need to verify that this particular purchase was made by a particular user. It especially important to prevent the possibility of changing the userId when you send for example userId and signed JSON to your server for verification purposes. But there are no such fields in signed JSON.

So is it OK to place some userId in `developerPayload` field ?

```
{ "nonce" : 1836535032137741465,
  "orders" :
    [{ "notificationId" : "android.test.purchased",
       "orderId" : "transactionId.android.test.purchased",
       "packageName" : "com.example.dungeons",
       "productId" : "android.test.purchased",
       "developerPayload" : "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ",
       "purchaseTime" : 1290114783411,
       "purchaseState" : 0,
       "purchaseToken" : "rojeslcdyyiapnqcynkjyyjh" }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is OK to place some user identity in the developer payload. When you receive that back in the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast you can then send this on to your own server.

This is especially relevant to unmanaged items where you need to maintain purchase and use of those items per user on your own server.

The real question is what user identity are you going to send and where are you going to get it from. It can't be device specific because a user may have multiple devices. It really needs to be an identity provided by Google Play. But I don't know how to find that.

Comment: Agree. This is how our Android team gives the proper purchaser the item he purchased. In our application, a user can sign out and sign in as a new user, and the response from Android In-App billing is not guaranteed to come in immediately or even shortly thereafter (can be hours later).